# Seperate JSX and function blocks from parent parentheses or parent tag

Tags: reactjs, vim, visual-studio-code, jsx, prettier

let say I have a React Component (class based for now, yeah i should start using hooks =D)

```js
class App extends Component {
  state = {
    someState: ""
  }  

  render() {
    return (
      <View>
        <View>
          <Text>Header</Text>
        </View>

        <View>
          <Text>Main</Text>
        </View>

        <View styles={styles.footer}>
          <Text>Footer</Text>
        </View>
      </View>
    )
  }
}
```

Now i am using **vimvscode** so i use `shift + [` or `shift + ]` a lot;

now let say i need to delete

```
state = {
  someState: ""
}
```

for me i think best way to delete that part i `d + shift + [`
if my cursor is at

```
  state = {
    someState: ""
  }[Cursor]
```

but it will delete up to `class App extends Component`

same goes for **JSX**

if i want to delete footer only

```
<View styles={styles.footer}>
  <Text>Footer<Text>
</View>
```

with `d + shift + ]` if my cursor is at:

it will delete all upto:

```
        <View styles={styles.footer}>
          <Text>Footer</Text>
        </View>
      </View>
    )
  }
}
```

I don't want this behaviour,

so i would love to know any **prettier configuration** or **vim plugin** that can help me do these stuff

Comment: Have you tried moving your cursor to `<Text>Footer</Text>` and `dit`?

Comment: thanks actually i want to delete whole footer contents not **Footer** text
from 
```<View styles={styles.footer}>
      <Text>Footer</Text><
   <View>
```

Comment: there is a vim plugin, i forgot its name and don't know how to use that in vscode

Comment: In that case `dat` should work. It does for me on neovim with no plugins.

Comment: but its not working